# How to fix btrfs extent issue

Tags: linux, btrfs

I think I have been hit by a known bug in btrfs:

https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg60984.html

Certainly, the error messages seem similar. If it is the same issue, it seems somewhat unfortunate that the fix for a 2 year old issue hasn't been ported into the V4.9 stable kernel (which is what Debian 9 uses)

I am now in the situation where one of the filesystem inodes has extent problems (as reported by `btrfs check`):

```
root 257 inode 2607184 errors 100, file extent discount
Found file extent holes:
       start: 0, len: 81920
```

It seems there isn't much advice or documentation on how to get out of such a situation (fortunately I do have backups of the filesystem concerned, so worst case could reformat and restore)

It seems `btrfs check --repair` just loops printing the same error over and over, without actually fixing it.

Is there any way to fix the existing filesystem, or am I best to recreate it and restore the backup?

Comment: Thanks - I went for a similar (but slightly more extreme) option of deleting the subvolume with the problems in. It seems freeing up the inode made the file system check cleanly. If you want to make an answer based on this, I will vote it as correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `root 257` refers to the subvolume ID, then `inode 2607184` points to the problematic inode. I would try to remove (unlink) every path linked to the inode.

1. Mount the subvolume:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdXN -o subvolid=257 /mnt/mountpoint
   ```
2. Locate every entry with matching inode number:

   ```
   find /mnt/mountpoint -xdev -inum 2607184
   ```
3. Investigate the objects. Hopefully you can afford to delete them.

   - (I'm not sure if it may be a directory in your case). If it's a directory, I suspect its listing may be incomplete.

     1. Move its contents (if any) to another, new directory (create it with the same ownership, permissions maybe); remove the old directory; `mv` the new directory to the old name.
     2. Compare to your backup, restore missing objects.
   - If it's one or more files –

     1. Remove them all.
     2. Restore the files from backup.
4. Unmount:

   ```
   umount /mnt/mountpoint
   ```
5. Check the filesystem. The problematic inode should be no more.

---

Alternatively you can delete the entire subvolume. This seems like overkill, yet it should get rid of the problematic inode.

1. Mount the root of the filesystem:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdXN -o subvol=/ /mnt/mountpoint
   ```
2. List subvolumes:

   ```
   btrfs subvolume list /mnt/mountpoint
   ```

   and locate the one with ID 257.
3. Delete the subvolume:

   ```
   btrfs subvolume delete -c /mnt/mountpoint/path/to/the/subvolume/with/ID/257
   ```
4. Unmount:

   ```
   umount /mnt/mountpoint
   ```
5. Check the filesystem. The problematic inode should be no more.
6. Restore your data from backup.

Comment: As it was newly created files that had triggered the bug (a git checkout), and I have periodic snapshot creation for use with Samba, I eventually accepted rolling back by 20 minutes in time and deleted the subvolume. `btrfs check` now reports no errors, hopefully there is no underlying corruption that will bite later

Comment: I had new files corrupted (filled with zeros) until I discovered the issue. `btrfs check ...` seems to have fixed it. I don't know yet what files are corrupted/lost :-(

Comment: Seems the USB hub used to connect the SSDs caused this.

Answer (score 0):

I have many files extents holes, which I located to the Firefox cache files (perhaps after an hard shutdown), thanks to Kamil Maciorowski's answer.

Same message, tens of:

> root 259 inode 11192417 errors 100, file extent discount
>
> Found file extent holes:
> start: 0, len: 475136

From [this duscussion](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-btrfs/CAGdWbB5Dc0=3YgR+DD=cyK-YHUUcOcUREgVD1-V6eozJXYKBBQ@mail.gmail.com/t/), it seems that this is not an issue:

> File extent discount is not a deal at all, kernel/progs/btrfs-fuse can
> all handle it well without problem.
>
> It's just the schema requires if a hole extent for each hole, for the
> old behavior.
>
> Nowadays, we have no-holes feature enabled for newer created fs, and
> kernel can handle this case very well.
>
> You can even able the feature on the fs by `btrfstune -n <device>`, and
> then btrfs check will never bother you on such file extent discount problem.

About `btrfstune -n`, the MAN says:

> -n
>
> ```
>       (since kernel: 3.14)
>
>       Enable no-holes feature (more efficient representation of file holes), enabled by mkfs feature no-holes.
> ```

And [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-btrfs/patch/20191111065004.24705-1-wqu@suse.com/) I found this:

> No-holes feature could save 53 bytes for each hole we have, and it
> provides a pretty good workaround to prevent btrfs check from reporting
> non-contiguous file extent holes for mixed direct/buffered IO.
>
> The latter feature is more helpful for developers for handle log-writes
> based test cases.

And indeed, `btrfstune -n` cleaned up my `btrfs check`.
I only got this message on my next `check`:

> cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated

that I fixed with `btrfs check --clear-space-cache v1`.

And now, all is good.

Hope this can help others who are facing this strange problem.